Открытие файла через скомпилированый py в exe файл
Нужна помощь как мне сделать чтоб если при открытие нужного мне файла, exe файлом у меня получало имя этого открытого rpf файла, если возможно такое на пайтоне если нет подскажите любой другой способ


В виндовсе есть функция когда нажимаешь правой кнопкой по файлу "открыть с помощью" и там можно выбрать через какой exe файл будет стартовать файл
И я хочу сделать так что если я так открываю файл таким способом я получаю название этого файла
добавил скриншот в вопрос

нашел решение
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])

